# Show Messages from a Library Project in a WPF Project

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, dll, .net-assembly

I have a project folder with two projects.
The first project (Project 1) is (will be) a library without views and pages, the second project (Project 2) is a WPF project with different views and pages and a view to display errors and information.
How can I now display errors and information from the library (Project 1) in this view (Project 2)?

I mean, for example, if an error occurs in the DLL (Project 1) in a method or function, this Info View should open in Project 2 and display the message (error / information).

I don't want to use message boxes, important!

Can someone give me some detailed information?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You should try to design your library project to show intentions to display a message (for example triggering an event), while the WPF project subscribes to it and display the suitable UI elements. Proper separation between business logic and UI is important to decouple different components in a complex system.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your information.
This is a global view, but I am missing in my head the approach to realize it. Maybe someone else can help?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i've created my own solution. In my Solution i've added a new library project like a view helper with a few views and functions...
Now i can access from all files of whole solution...

This entry can closed ;-)